# How to describe the transformation $\sin(3x)$ to $\sin(3x+\frac{7\pi}{4})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In my precalculus lab I read the following question incorrectly and hence I believe I have given them incorrect information.

> Describe how you can obtain the graph of $y = \sin(3x + \frac{7\pi}{4})$ from the graph of $y = \sin(3x)$.

I initially read the second equation as $y = \sin(x)$. To me this requires a different set of transformations to obtain the desired graph: horizontal compression by a factor of $\frac13$ and apply a horizontal shift of $\frac{7\pi}{12}$ to the left.

Going from $\sin(3x)$ to $\sin(3x + \frac{7\pi}{4})$ requires a horizontal shift of $\frac{7\pi}{4}$ units to the left. I'm imagining what I'd call the "$(3x)y$-plane", i.e. the typical cartesian plane where the horizontal axis is labeled as "3x" instead of the usual "x"

Please help with the following:

1. Is my correction correct? (Sorry if that sounds weird)
2. How would you explain this to a group of precalculus students?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need to re-label anything. Also write it as $\sin(3[x+\frac{7 \pi}{12}[)$

Comment: @randomgirl: This was my initial response to my students, but for some reason it feels odd.

Comment: @randomgirl: To me writing $\sin\left[ 3(x + \frac{7\pi}{12}) \right]$ is telling me what transformations to apply to $\sin(x)$ to obtain the desired graph. I don't believe it tells the correct transformations to apply to $\sin(3x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph of $y=\sin\left(3x + \frac{7\pi}{4} \right)$ has exactly the same shape as $y=\sin\left(3x  \right)$ but shifted $ \frac{7\pi}{12}$ units to the left.  The easiest way to see this is to use function notation:  If
$$f(x) = \sin\left(3x\right)$$
then 
$$f\left(x + \frac{7\pi}{12} \right)=\sin\left(3\left(x+\frac{7\pi}{12}\right)\right)=\sin\left(3x + \frac{7\pi}{4} \right)$$
whereas
$$f\left(x + \frac{7\pi}{4} \right)=\sin\left(3\left(x+\frac{7\pi}{4}\right)\right)=\sin\left(3x + \frac{21\pi}{4} \right)$$

Comment: I somehow think I lead myself into thinking that $3x$ is the independent variable which lead me to relabeling the horizontal axis. Silly me.